# GoogleMapsAPIをJSON形式で取得　→　”Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : ”

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

AngularJSでGoogleMapAPIを用いてJSON形式のレスポンスを取得したいのですが、
コンソールに"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"とエラー表示されます。
レスポンスのJSONに":"が存在する為、このエラーが発生するのでしょうか？
解決方法はありますでしょうか？

どなたかわかる方いらっしゃいましたら、
ご教示いただけると幸いです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

---------- ソース ----------

```
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.jsonp('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Tokyo&destinations=Kyoto&mode=Driving&sensor=false', {
            params: {
                callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
            }
        }).success(function(response){
            console.dir(data,status,headers,config);
            deferred.resolve(data);   
        }).error(function(data,status,headers,config){
            deferred.reject(status);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
```

---------- コンソール出力 ----------

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : (18:20:02:095 | error, javascript)
      at https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Tokyo&destinations=Kyoto&mode=Driving&sensor=false&callback=angular.callbacks._0:2
```

---------- コンソールのリンク先（GoogleMapsAPIのレスポンス） ----------

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Kyoto, Kyoto Prefecture, Japan" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Tokyo, Japan" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "457 km",
                  "value" : 456931
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "5 hours 39 mins",
                  "value" : 20338
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

レスポンスのJSONは問題ないように見えます。
それよりは実際に使われるURLの末尾
`&callback=angular.callbacks._0:2`
の`:2`が怪しい気がします。

Jsonpメソッド呼び出しを次のようにしてみてはいかがでしょうか。

```
 $http.jsonp('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Tokyo&destinations=Kyoto&mode=Driving&sensor=false&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
.[ここから先は同じ]
```

Answer (score 1):

AngularJSを使用した経験がないため、的はずれであればごめんなさい。

コンソール出力にある、APIのリクエストに使われたURLをブラウザで表示すると、質問者さんの投稿にあるとおりのレスポンスが返ってきています。しかし、Googleマップが返しているレスポンスはJSON形式であるのに対し、[Qiitaに投稿されていたこちらの記事](http://qiita.com/laiso/items/19c722b5bea6838f5ad8)では、`$http.jsonp`メソッドが受け取るレスポンスは、メソッド名の通りJSONP形式であるべきなように見えます。

JSONPとJSONの差は、JSON形式ではデータ全体が純粋なJSONフォーマットに準拠しているのに対し、JSONP形式では、リクエスト時に指定されたJavascript関数の呼び出しの際に、引数としてJSONフォーマットのデータを呼び出す**Javascriptコード**である点です（詳しくは[こちらの記事](http://taiju.hatenablog.com/entry/20090902/1251851867)がわかりやすいかと思われます）。エラーメッセージとの整合性がとれるかよくわからないのですが、JSONP形式のデータが渡されるべきところにJSON形式のデータが渡されているのが原因ではないかと考えています。

[こちらの記事](http://qiita.com/hkusu/items/61127838300d1b429091)では、`$http`を使用してJSONを取得しています。souzさんの回答のようなURLの修正をされてなお動いていなければ、こちらをお試しいただければと思います。